# How to solve ambiguous template overload of clear on local array?

Tags: d

Currently, I try to get the latest version of facebook's flint to get compiled.

The code fails with the D compiler version 2.081.1 on a similar construct as

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
    long[] foo = [];
    foo.clear();
}
```

Here is the short link to the example: https://run.dlang.io/is/ZSsPNS

with the messages:

```
onlineapp.d(5): Error: template object.clear cannot deduce function 
from argument types !()(long[]), candidates are:
/dlang/dmd/linux/bin64/../../src/druntime/import/object.d(2855):        
object.clear(T : Value[Key], Value, Key)(T aa)
/dlang/dmd/linux/bin64/../../src/druntime/import/object.d(2860):        
object.clear(T : Value[Key], Value, Key)(T* aa)
```

How can this ambiguity be solved?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity there - `clear` is a function that operates on associative arrays, not dynamic arrays, which is what `long[]` is.

Now, that of course doesn't mean the code works. :p

The issue is `clear` was renamed to `destroy` in 2.066, and removed in 2.070. Then, in 2.071, the current function was introduced, which clears AAs of their contents.

So, in summary: replace `clear` with `destroy`, and things should work.

Comment: If there was ambiguity btw, you can use the full name like `whatever.import.here.clear(foo);` instead. but indeed here you can use `destroy`, or just reassign it to `null`..